# How to parse form array in golang Beego

Tags: html, forms, go

How to parse html form array with Beego.

`<input name="names[]" type="text" />
<input name="names[]" type="text" />
<input name="names[]" type="text" />`

Go Beego

```html
type Rsvp struct {
    Id    int      `form:"-"`
    Names []string `form:"names[]"`
}

rsvp := Rsvp{}
if err := this.ParseForm(&rsvp); err != nil {
    //handle error
}

input := this.Input()
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", input) // map[names[]:[name1 name2 name3]]
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", rsvp) // {Names:[]}
```

Why Beego ParseForm method return an empty names?

How to get values into rsvp.Names?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @ysqi for giving me a hint. I am adding a little detailed example to parse associate array like form data in beego

Here is my form structure:

```
<input name="contacts[0][email]" type="text" value="a1@gmail.com"/>
<input name="contacts[0][first_name]" type="text" value="f1"/>
<input name="contacts[0][last_name]" type="text" value="l1"/>
<input name="contacts[1][email]" type="text" value="a2@gmail.com"/>
<input name="contacts[1][first_name]" type="text" value="f2"/>
<input name="contacts[1][last_name]" type="text" value="l2"/>
```

golang(beego) code:

```
contacts := make([]map[string]string, 0, 3)

this.Ctx.Input.Bind(&contacts, "contacts")
```

contacts variable:

```
[
  {
    "email": "user2@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Sam",
    "last_name": "Gamge"
  },
  {
    "email": "user3@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "john",
    "last_name": "doe"
  }
]
```

Now you can use it like:

```
for _, contact := range contacts {
    contact["email"]
    contact["first_name"]
    contact["last_name"]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from the implementation of the FormValue method of the Request, it returns the first value in case of multiple ones:
http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/request.go?s=23078:23124#L795
It would be better to get the attribute itself r.Form[key] and iterate over all the results manually. I am not sure how Beego works, but just using the raw 
Request.ParseForm and Request.Form or Request.PostForm maps should do the job.
http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/request.go?s=1939:6442#L61

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this : see [doc](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/params.md)

```
v := make([]string, 0, 3)
this.Ctx.Input.Bind(&v, "names")
```